# SharePoint 2013 Performance issue / tuning

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I found out that when I open SharePoint Site with new SPSite object, it's too slow to respond.

```
using(SPSite s = new SPSite(siteURL) //30 seconds
{    
   ...    
}
```

I did try the following method, however the method did not gain significant performance boost, may I ask your help for performance issue?

- Warm-up script:

http://www.justinkobel.com/post/2013/08/16/My-SharePoint-2013-%28and-2010%29-Warm-up-Script

http://www.jonthenerd.com/2011/04/19/easy-sharepoint-2010-warmup-script-using-powershell/

- Disable distributed cache

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65695/sharepoint-2013-extremely-slow

Comment: How long does it take for the site to load in a browser? There's nothing really wrong with your code; slow performance may be due to insufficient system resources (low memory etc.) as SharePoint 2013 is a memory hog. How much RAM does your SharePoint/SQL Server server have?

Comment: the SharePoint server have 24 GB RAM installed, and the SQL Server have 12 GB RAM installed.

Answer (score 0):

I would check on whats really going on when creating this SPSite object. Monitor the outgoing requests from your SharePoint instance to that URL to see whether time is spent on your IIS - on the Network - or on the SharePoint Site that you try to connect.
If you dont know how to do this check out free tools such as Dynatrace which allows you to do exactly this. I wrote several blogs about the top performance problems with SharePoint - you may find that interesting: http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2010/03/18/how-to-avoid-the-top-5-sharepoint-performance-mistakes/ - #3 on this blog also talks about a potential memory leak with SPSite and SPWeb objects - so - check this out